# include path problem when building a simple library with bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

The demo structure like this:

```
.
├── demo
│    ├── include
│    │     └── func.h
│    │    
│    └── src
│          ├── BUILD
│          │
│          └── func.cc
└── WORKSPACE
```

func.h:

```
#pragma once

int square(int);
```

func.cc: include from the root

```
#include "demo/include/func.h"

int square(int i) { return i * i; }
```

BUILD:

```
cc_library(
    name = "simple_demo",
    srcs = ["func.cc"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Bazel build command in the dir of `WORKSPACE`:

```
bazel build //demo/src:simple_demo
```

The error occurs.

```
demo/src/func.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'demo/include/func.h' file not found
```

And I saw this in https://docs.bazel.build/versions/1.1.0/be/c-cpp.html#hdrs

```
All header files that are used in the build must be declared in the hdrs or srcs of cc_* rules. This is enforced.
```

However, if I add `hdrs = "../include/func.h"` to the `BUILD`, another error will occur

```
segment '..' not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in Bazel labels are not allowed to cross the package boundaries. In your case `func.h` lives outside the package defined by the `BUILD` file, that is limited to `demo/src` (and sub-folders).

Assuming you're creating a library where `func.h` is the public header visible from outside, I would change the folder structure to:

```
.
├── demo
│    ├── include
│    │     └── func.h
│    ├── src
│    │     └── func.cc
│    └── BUILD
└── WORKSPACE
```

and the `BUILD` file to also include `func.h`:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "simple_demo",
    hdrs = ["include/func.h"],
    srcs = ["src/func.cc"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Notice that even with the suggested folder structure, if you don't include the `hdrs = ...` line (or don't include `func.h` in `srcs = ...`, if the header is not meant to be public), you will get an error for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: I wonder, how does Bazel intends to structure tests? If in your workspace you have src/ and test/, how can I include headers from /src/ into tests/ assuming they build different targets?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this might work, but can you try giving

> '../include/func.h'

instead of 'demo/include/func.h' because I believe its not able to find a demo folder inside your src folder since it starts searching from there.

Comment: Bazel best practices suggest `Make all include paths relative to the workspace directory.`.