# Include path has been specified but still failed to include the header in the path in a Bazel C++ project

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

I have projects with a directory structure like that

```
---root
|  |--src
|    |--project1
|      |--model
|      |  |--incude
|      |  |  |--model
|      |  |    |--modelA.hpp
|      |  |    |--modelB.hpp
|      |  |--modelA.cpp
|      |  |--modelB.cpp
|      |  |--BUILD #1
|      |...
|      |--view
|      |...
|      |--common
|      |  |--include
|      |    |--common
|      |      |--data_type.hpp 
|      |--BUILD #2
|--WORKSPACE
```

As I have other package in this project and some of them use the same self-defined data type, I defined them in a package named `common`.

Now I include the `data_type.hpp` in file `modelA.hpp`

```
...
#include "common/data_type.hpp
...
```

Refering to the stage3 example in the [tutorial](https://bazel.build/start/cpp), the `BUID`(#1) is like that

```
cc_library(
  name = "modelA",
  hdrs = "include/model/modelA.hpp",
  deps = ["//src/project/common:data_type"],
  copts = ["-Isrc/project/common/include"],
)
```

and the `BUILD`(#2) which defines the depedency module `data_type`is like that

```
cc_library(
  name = "data_type",
  hdrs = ["include/common/data_type.hpp"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

However, when I built the code, I got

```
src/project/model/include/model/modelA.hpp: fatal error: common/data_type.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Why I have defined `copts = ["-Isrc/heimdallr/common/include"]` but still got this error?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [Header inclusion checking](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/1.1.0/be/c-cpp.html#hdrs) section of [C/C++ Rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/1.1.0/be/c-cpp.html#c-c-rules) from the Bazel document. Relative to the workspace directory, all include paths should be created. Kindly refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869739/include-path-problem-when-building-a-simple-library-with-bazel) for more information. Thank you!